# Facebook comments box shows Warning:URL is unreachable for 7-8 hours

Tags: facebook, comments

I have a blog that I have a FB comments box on. When I post the blog I see the comment box showing warning 'http://story.pxd.co.kr/512 is unreachable' for 7-8 hours. (After 7-8 hours, this warning message disappears automatically!)

Do you know why it takes so long?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what's the problem? Every time you add a new post you get this message? If so, is it just for the new post or the all of the posts get that message? The more info you give, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right. Every time I add a new post, I get this message for the new post. (Old posts do not have this message) And 4 hour-8 hour later, the message disappears. And I did check this URL with FB debugger, but I cannot interpret(understand) the errors...

Comment: It will be hard to help you with out the ability to know more, or see it for myself. So, can post in your question the errors you get in the debugger?

Comment: I don't have any "new" post that has the warning right now. But you can see it on the debugger for one of the old posts(http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstory.pxd.co.kr%2F516) I just found that I can remove the warning by putting the url into facebook debugger. Is there any way I can remove the waring automatically without using debugger

Comment: Looks like you are missing some open graph meta tags, they are those who start with *og:*. Check out the [documentation for that](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).